# How to put a filter on a multivalue parameter to not display all the value in the dropdown

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

Hi i have a report where i have **two parameters** one is **Customer number** and other is **DIVISION_NO**; both the parameters are **multi-value** and getting their value from two different data-set. the parameter Division number depends on customer number(to each customer_no is associated one or multiple division_no)  so once customer_no parameter is populated then i can populate division number. Now **For one particular Customer_no** i want to display one particular division number only, so all the other division_no associated to that particular Customer_no i don't want to shown them in the drop down list.

Can anyone help me in this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create and pass in the Customer_No as a variable, eg @CustomerNo, into dataset for the Division_No parameter

Ensure the Division Parameter is listed below the Customer_no parameter in the list

Make the Division_No dataset  something similar to:

```
IF @CustomerNo = <restricted_Cust>
BEGIN
    select Division_no
    from   table
    where  CustomerNo = @CustomerNo
    AND    Division_no IN (restricted list)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select Division_no
    from   table
    where  CustomerNo = @CustomerNo
END
```

Comment: My Division_no Data set is already like this, infect that's why i mentioned above that devision_no depends on customer_no.  But my real prob is that i have now one particular Customer_no for which i don't want to show all the Division_no associated; basically i want to filter the Data set of Division_no for that particular Customer_no.

Comment: @deep, see updated answer, use an IF condition in the dataset based on the CustomerNo variable